# jQuery-Ui loses functionality after reloaded to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Hey I am have a site with jQuery-UI obgects in a table.
What I do is to save the table in localstorage, this way the user can load different "projects".

Now after I load a saved Table I also update the handlers of all my buttons ect. whitch work fine after that. But the functionality of all the jQuery-Uis is no longer given. I tried following code in the updateHandlers function:

```
//Initial setup for jQuery UI
$( '#infoImg' ).tooltip();
$( '#volSlider' ).slider({ max: 100, min: 0});
```

but this only works for the first apperance of the elements in my table. all the others don't work.

I'm just a beginner with jQuery and Javascript and maybe I'm doing something completely wrong.. but what is it?

I tired other stuff in the updateHandler function:

```
$(this).parent().find( '.infoImg' ).tooltip();
$(this).parent().find( '.volSlider' ).slider({ max: 100, min: 0});
```

But now its not working for any one..

the HTML is:

```
    <img id="infoImg" src="images/info_s.png" height="30" width="30" title="What">
<div id="volSlider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 18%;"></a></div>
```

this code repeats itself in every row of my table..

I have now also tried it with the .each() function of jQuery.. with no success:

```
 $('.volSlider').each(function(index, elem) {
                $(this).slider({ max: 100, min: 0});
            });
```

I'm happy to post additional Info or code if you need any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it with help of the `each()` function:

```
$.each($('.volSlider'), function() {
        $(this).slider({ max: 100, min: 0});
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first piece of code: the initial setup you select the handlers by id `$('#infoImt')`. While after an update you use a class selector `$('.infoImg')`. You are not referring to the same object. That's why it doesn't work.

Just a heads-up: make sure any existing elements first drop their functionality, before you add the updated.

**EDIT**

Try the following function:

```
var initFn = function(){
    $('.infoImg.__new')
    .tooltip()
    .removeClass('__new');

    $('.volSlider.__new')
    .slider({max:100,min:0})
    .removeClass('__new');
};
```

As you can see, I've added a class: `__new`. This class is the 'actual' selector. This will make sure you don't apply `.tooltip()` and `.slider()` twice on the same element. You'd have to change you HTML a bit as well:

```
<img class="infoImg __new" src="images/info_s.png" height="30" width="30" title="What" />
<div class="volSlider __new ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">
    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 18%;"></a>
</div>
```

Notice that I've changed `id` into `class` and that I've added the `__new` class. Let me know if this works.

Comment: My English isn't the best sorry.. but what I do is replace the innerHTML of my table with the saved one. So afterwards all my slidebars and tooltips don't work anymore. In my initial setup, only the first occurance of my tooltip and slider work again, all the others dont..

Comment: And I have tried it with "$(this).parent().find( '#infoImg' ).tooltip();" but it made no difference.

Comment: That could be because those elements aren't where your query is pointing at (`$(this).parent().find(...`). Also watch out with duplicate ID's: you cannot use the same ID on two different elements.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to class="infoImg" but it didnt help.

$( '.infoImg' ).each(function()
  {this.tooltip()}); <-- was somethig i tried but also doeas not work.

Comment: the HTML is: <div id="volSlider" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false"><a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 18%;"></a></div>    and   <img id="infoImg" src="images/info_s.png" height="30" width="30" title="What">

Answer (score 0):

change that:

```
//Initial setup for jQuery UI

$( '#infoImg' ).tooltip();
$( '#volSlider' ).slider({ max: 100, min: 0});
```

to this:

```
$( '.infoImg' ).tooltip();
$( '.volSlider' ).slider({ max: 100, min: 0});
```

Comment: the problem is, it only works for the first appearance of the infoImg.. I can show you the full HTML block.. will edit straight away.. I also changed the infoImg to have a class no longer an ID

Comment: Id must be unique within the document, therefore change all id="infoImg" on class="infoImg", and id="volSlider" on class="volSlider"
After that first fragment of code fix to:
$( '.infoImg' ).tooltip();
$( '.volSlider' ).slider({ max: 100, min: 0});
And try